# rounded textview by code

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to create a rounded Textview during runtime per Code ? I know it would be possible with layout-definition in XML, but I like to do it per code.

```
TextView tvnew = new TextView(mContext);
tvnew.setcorner=5px; ?????????
```

regards

Comment: There some libraries which is called RoundedImageView. You can read the codes from that.

Hope it helps. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do it with a textview.

Comment: I know, i think that library overrides onDraw method. You can try to copy that code :)

Comment: please explain the type of textView you want probably by uploading some image??? that will help answering in a more clear manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an xml file in drawable folder as roundedback.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF404040" />
<corners android:radius="6dp" />
<gradient android:startColor="#FF6800" android:centerColor="#FF8000" android:endColor="#FF9700" android:angle="90" /> 
</shape>
```

and then in your code, do
`tvnew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedback);`

Comment: Thanks a lot this works. But how can I round dynamically ? I mean I would like to adjust the cornersize depending on the device density. Or is dp proportional to the device screen-density ?

Comment: yes you can specify values in dp so that the design will not change from device to device